# When invading another player, do I get any benefit from killing other phantoms?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm pretty new to pvp and actually I'm a member of the Brotherhood of Blood. I usually duel over the bridge at the iron keep, using the red sign soap. Sometimes (pretty often) I'm summoned in a world where the host has already summoned multiple red phantoms or white / gold phantoms. Sometimes the red phantom is friend with the host and team up with him and I have to fight 1v2 or 1v3. Often the host hides behind multiple players or summons white phantoms in sequence and I have to kill them before reach him. 
My question is: do I have some benefits killing other red phantoms or white phantoms during an invasion?

If not, it would be pretty sad. Yes, I'm built for pvp (even if I'm not great at it), but last invasion I had to face 3 white phantoms before killing the host (which was hiding / healing  and summoning) to get only one token of spite.

Comment: As far as i know from my experience, you only gain souls.

Comment: So what's the point of fighting between invaders? I mean, in the end they both want a token of spite and going 2v1 is much easier than fighting each others and then fight the host. I often see hosts summoning 2-3 red phantoms and just watch them fight and keep summoning (to farm souls I guess). But I do not understand why the invader should agree with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real point to fighting other invaders, most people are just in the mindset that if you invade, you have to kill everything you can. However, as you stated above, any and all players receive a token of spite, and souls from the kill, so all's well that ends well.

The only reason that invaders try and kill other invaders is simply to get more souls.

Sometimes hosts use Red Summon Signs to create a "fight club" for red summons to battle it out, mostly for fun, sometimes for farming. In this instance no-one is really looking to fight the host for any special rewards - they're just in it for the PvP.

Answer (score 0):

When you're invading and the host has phantoms if you are able to kill those phantoms you will get souls from them. Now if you invade or get summoned to a "fight club" you fight other invaders which you get souls for killing them. Most fight clubs are meant for the host to get free souls off of the invaders fighting cause when a summon/invader dies everyone in that game gets souls